# React-Native-Maps how to draw polylines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apple-maps

I've started using https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps and having no luck drawing polylines from an array of array coordinates on the map.

I am not sure if I'm passing in the array of coordinates correctly.

this is how I am rendering the polyline:

```
      {this.state.polylines.map(polyline => (
        <MapView.Polyline
          key={polyline.id}
          coordinates={polyline.coordinates}
          strokeColor="#000"
          fillColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
          strokeWidth={1}/>
      ))}
```

**polyline.coordinates** looks like:

```
      [[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng]]
```

Thank you for any help/advice :D

Comment: How did you get the Array of Lat and Lng ??? [ [lat,lng ],[lat,lng ] ] . .??\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the coordinates must be an array of type `LatLng` as it is documented in the [API](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md).

How `LatLng` objects are created can be found in the component `MapMarker` for example. Here you can find the [source code](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/components/MapMarker.js#L60) (linked to the relevant line) and the [component API](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md).

Hope this will help you,
Marius

Comment: You are right, the MapView.Polyline component takes a prop coordinates which should be an array of lat/lng coordinate pair objects.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to hear that this could solve your problem :)

Comment: If you're using your own map tiles, it may help to add "zIndex={1}" to the Polyline props to make the lines visible.  I note this b/c I found this page while researching a similar issue with a Polygon not showing up.